# Resourse Router - Only route for entries in one channel

Tags: resource-router

Is there a way to use Resources Router to only route for entries in one particular channel, then for everything else, use the normal EE template structure?

I've tried:

```
':any'  => function($router, $wildcard_furniture) {
           if ($wildcard_furniture->isValidEntry(array('channel' => 'furniture'))) {
           $router->setTemplate('product-category/index');
         } else {
      $router->stopRouting();
    }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$config['resource_router'] = array(

    ':any' => function($router, $wildcard) {
        if ($wildcard->isValidUrlTitle( array('channel' => 'furniture') )) {
            $router->setTemplate('product-category/index');
        }
    },

};
```

If there's no match then no template would be set and ee carries on.

I would think it's faster if you can narrow the url possibility down because then that db call will only happen on matched pages (i.e.: domain.com/furniture/chair):

```
    'furniture/:any' => function($router, $wildcard) {
        if ($wildcard->isValidUrlTitle ... etc....
```